# Simplest way to host a static webpage in AWS with a single case-sensitive response header

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge, connman

I'm trying to create a simple webpage for a [ConnMan connectivity check](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ConnMan) from some embedded devices. This library is very finicky about certain things.

The body must be: `<html>\n<head>\n</head>\n<body>\n</body>\n</html>\n` If anything, even the trailing newline at the end is missing, it fails.

The other component is a response header of `X-ConnMan-Status: online`. Normally response headers are case insensitive, but ConnMan fails if case is changed at all. This is a seemingly unimportant detail, until you try to host it with AWS.

My first thought was CloudFront (CDN) as it is static content. I also would like to find a serverless solution, as I don't want to manage EC2 instances or K8s pods. I setup a CloudFront distribution with an S3 bucket as the backend to host the simple HTML response. This works great.

I then started exploring various ways of adding the response header. So far I have tried:

- [CloudFront Function](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/) to add the header
- [CloudFront Response Header Policy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-cloudfront-introduces-response-headers-policies/) to add the header
- [Lambda@edge function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html) to add the header

All work to add the response header, but Amazon has some crazy obsession with converting the header names to lower case and I need it to be `X-ConnMan-Status` not `x-connman-status`. Is there a simple way to host this in AWS where it won't lower case the response header name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually realized that the lower casing of the header names was due to HTTP/2: https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#HttpHeaders

> header field names MUST be converted to lowercase prior to their encoding in HTTP/2. A request or response containing uppercase header field names MUST be treated as malformed

Disabling HTTP/2 support on the CloudFront distribution, or requesting HTTP/1.1 with the client, preserves the header casing.